# How to correctly delegate devise username and associate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-6

Goal: Associate Devise username with post. I am getting this error after trying to delegate the username in the post model and return in my view. From what I understand there is two ways to do this. Method/Delegation pattern or Law of Demeter. I installed Devise gem and that should be set up correctly and installed views. I also tried delegate without the prefix, same error. Also tried @post.username... Any help appreciated.

[image]

posts/index.html.erb

```
<% content_for :page_title do %>
  <h1 class="title is-4 has-text-centered m-3" style="margin-top: 2em">
posts
</h1>
<% end %>

<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
          <div class="media">
            <div class="media-content">
              <p class="title is-4"><%= link_to post.title, post %></p>
              <p><%= post.username %></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            <%= post.content.first(120) %>...
          </div>
          <div class="comment-count">
            <span class="tag is-rounded">comment count</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</section>
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, :content, presence: true
  has_many :opinions
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :username, to: :user, prefix: true
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

post_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # create follows create route to create new post
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # view rendered to update post
  def edit 
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # method to edit post
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    redirect_to posts_path
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.required(:post).permit(:title, :content)
  end

end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :users

  resources :posts do
    resources :opinions
  end
  get '/user' => "posts#index", :as => :user_root
  root 'post#index'
end
```

posts table migration

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :content

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

add user id to posts

```
class AddUserIdToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_reference :posts, :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Devise create users migration added

```
t.string :username
```

Answer (score 0):

in you error message we see: user_id = nil, that mean  when you create post you dont create reference to user, you should change you view to new post and after this create new posts. Also if you want to find username by post author you should write something like this: post.user.username. Pardon for my poor choice of words and i only start learn rails so sorry if something wrong